# Amazon Marketplace app rejected for containing Eclipse settings file

Tags: java, android, compilation, amazon-appstore

I'm currently trying to submit my app to the Amazon Marketplace. Today I received the following email from the App Testing team:

> Your recent submission of RSS Alarm is pending due to the following reason(s):
>
> We are having trouble publishing your app to test. Your APK appears to have the following file included in it: .settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs Please remove this file and resubmit your APK.
>
> Please correct the issue(s) we found with your app submission so we may continue working to get it in the Appstore.

Thing is, I can't see how the .settings folder made it into the APK build in the first place. It's not listed in either my Android settings nor my Java build path settings. So where am I going wrong with this?

**Screenshots:**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the .settings directory listed in the project pane in Eclipse? If so, you may be able to right click on it and select "Exclude from project" or something similar.

Comment: Yes, but there's no option to exclude it.

Comment: Ok. I thought there might be something like that but I could be wrong. I don't have Eclipse on the machine I'm currently using so I can't check right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From working in a team environment I've made it a habit of keeping my application source and resources in a separate directory tree from my workspace and project settings. For example:

```
/home/workspaces/projectname

/home/sources/projectname
```

I don't know if this is your exact problem but I think it might help keep Eclipse meta-data from being built with your code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out. Do you know of any documentation on how to separate workspace files from source files in an existing project?

Comment: @Michael, there probably is documentation somewhere though I'm not sure where. What I usually do is after I create the project, I create an empty directory somewhere for the source and link to it in the project settings. In your second screenshot above it would be the "Link Source..." button I believe. Once that link is made I usually remove the default folders from that list so I don't accidentally create new source files in those folders.

Comment: Right, I've just created a new test Android project, and the .settings folder isn't present in that project. It might be a remnant of a previous version of Eclipse or ADT, so I've deleted it for now. The .settings folder is under version control in case deleting it causes any complications further down the line.

Let's just hope that's enough to float Amazon's boat!

Comment: Didn't work. Amazon just rejected it for the same reason. I'll give you the points anyway though since I'd rather just give up on Amazon. Been reading some [rather disturbing](http://www.insidemobileapps.com/2011/04/14/igda-warns-against-amazon-appstores-pricing-terms-but-doesnt-mention-in-app-payments/) things about their T&Cs.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this problem, delete the file named `org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs` in your project source folder (lib.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings).